# My program isn't saving/displaying all the bills I've added

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, hash, conditional-statements

I've flirted with learning web dev in the past and haven't had the time as I am a full time Business Student.

I started digging back in today and decided to take a break from the learning and practice what I've learned today by writing a simple program that allows the user to enter in their bills and will eventually calculate how much disposable income they have after their bills are paid each month.

My problem is that the program runs through perfectly, the loop is continuing/exiting when it should, but either the program is not storing the users input in the hash like I'm wanting it to or it's not displaying all the bills entered as it should. Here is my program:

```
# This program allows you to assign monthly payments
# to their respective bills and will automatically
# calculate how much disposable income you have
# after your bills are paid

# Prompts user to see if they have any bills to enter
puts "Do you have any bills you would like to enter, Yes or No?"
new_bill = gets.chomp.downcase
 until new_bill == 'no'

# Creates a hash to store a key/value pair 
# of the bill name and the respection payment amount

    bills = {}
    puts "Enter the bill name: "
    bill_name = gets.chomp
    puts "How much is this bill?"
    pay_amt = gets.chomp

    bills[bill_name] = pay_amt

    puts "Would you like to add another bill, Yes or No?"
    new_bill = gets.chomp.downcase
end

bills.each do |bill_name, pay_amt|
  puts "Your #{bill_name} bill is $#{pay_amt}."
end
```

My questions are: 
Is my hash set up properly to store the key/value pairs from the users input? 
If not, how can I correct it?

I'm getting only the last bill that was entered by the user. I've tried several bills at a time but only getting the last entry.

As I stated, I'm a noob but I'm extremely ambitious to learn. I've referred to to the ruby docs on hashes to see if there is an error in my code but was able to locate a solution (still finding my way around ruby docs).

Any help is appreciated! Also, if you have any recommendations on ways I can make my code more efficient, could you point me in the direction where I can obtain the appropriate information to do so?

Thank you.

Edit:

The main question has been answered. This is a follow up question to the same program - I'm getting an error message budget_calculator.rb:35:in `-': Hash can't be coerced into Float (TypeError)
    from budget_calculator.rb:35:in`'

From the following code (keep in mind of the program above) -

```
# Displays the users bills
bills_hash.each {|key,value| puts "Your #{key} bill is $#{value}."}

# Get users net income
puts "What is your net income?"
net_income = gets.chomp.to_f

#Calculates the disposable income of the user
disposable_income = net_income - bills_hash.each {|value| value}

puts disposable_income
```

I understand the error is appearing from this line of code:
    disposable_income = net_income - bills_hash.each {|value| value}

I'm just not understanding why this is unacceptable. I'm trying to subtract all of the values in the hash (pay_amt) from the net income to derive the disposable income.

Comment: If anyone has an idea about the error message, that part still has not been answer.

Comment: I found the answer to the second part of the question by using Enumerable#inject to total the pay_amt values in the hash then subtracting the total from the net income. Here is the following code solution: tot_bills = bills_hash.values.inject { |a,b| a+b }

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't expect multiple questions to be answered in one page unless they're extremely close; Multiple questions are difficult to answer clearly and they're difficult for others to follow when searching for similar solutions. Remember, SO is a reference book or programming cookbook for solutions to specific problems. Also, please be very concise when asking; Programming is concise and we like brevity. "Thanks" and "Edit" aren't desirable either; We assume you're thankful, and "Edit" or "Update" only distracts. Put the text where it should have been initially.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the part that's getting you:

```
bills = {}
```

You're resetting the hash every time the program loops. Try declaring `bills` at the top of the program.

---

As to your second question about `bills_hash`, it's not working because the program is attempting to subtract a hash from a float. You've got the right idea, but the way it's set up, it's not going to just subtract each key from the `net_income` in turn.

The return value of `#each` is the original hash that you were looping over. You can see this if you open IRB and type

```
[1,2,3].each {|n| puts n}
```

The block is evaluated for each element of the list, but the final return value is the original list:

```
irb(main):007:0> [1,2,3].each {|n| puts n}
1
2
3
=> [1, 2, 3]   # FINAL RETURN VALUE
```

So according to the order of operations, your `#each` block is iterating, then returning the original `bills_hash` hash, and then trying to subtract that hash from `net_income`, which looks like this (assuming my `net_income` is 1000):

```
1000 - {rent: 200, video_games: 800}
```

hence the error.

There are a couple ways you could go about fixing this. One would be to sum all of the values in `bills_hash` as its own variable, then subtract that from the `net_income`:

```
total_expenditures = bills_hash.values.inject(&:+) # sum the values
disposable_income = net_income - total_expenditures
```

Using the same `#inject` method, this could also be done in one function call:

```
disposable_income = bills_hash.values.inject(net_income, :-) 
# starting with net_income, subtract each value in turn
```

See the documentation for [`Enumerable#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject).

It's a very powerful and useful method to know. But make sure you go back and understand how return values work and why the original setup was raising an exception.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That was exactly my probem; noob mistake.

Comment: You're welcome! Would you mind marking this as the correct answer?

Comment: I tried, but I don't have a level 15 badge yet so I'm unable to mark it. Once I'm able to, I will come back and mark it.

Comment: @ZachWilliams I've gone back and edited my answer to explain the second issue you described above.